# A question about the proof that $f_n\to f $ in $L^p$ iff $\lbrace \vert f_n\vert^p\rbrace$ is Uniformly Integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

**Update**: The following question is about a proof of Theorem 8, Section 7.3 of Royden's Real Analysis, 4e. *How is the fact that $\lbrace \vert f\vert^p\rbrace$ is integrable over $E$ used in the last sentence?* I am not interested in "tightness," only the "uniformly integrable" part.

**Warning!**:The errata says that the $f$ should be a $f_n$ in the final line of the statement of the theorem.

[image]

I can't see how this fact along with the last two inequalities are being used in the conclusion.

Comment: I don't really think the statement is true at all, because the property that "$\{|f|^p\}$ is uniformly integrated and tight" has nothing to do with the sequence $(f_n)_n$.

Comment: Oops. The errata says that the $f$ should be a $f_n$ in the final line of the statement of the theorem.

Comment: By tight sequence of measurable functions $(g_n)_n$ you mean tightness of the sequence of signed measures $(\mu_n)_n$ given by $\mu_n(E)=\int_E f$ ?

Comment: what book is this from?

Comment: @Aram The text is Royden's Real Analysis 4e.

Comment: @Pipicito I am only interested in the "uniformly integrable" part. I'll edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence of functions $f_n$ is uniformly integrable if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all measurable set $A$ with $m(A) < \delta$ we have $\int \vert f_n \vert <\varepsilon.$

If you have two sequences $g_n$ and $h_n$ and you can show that $C |h_n| \leq |g_n| \leq \frac{1}{C} |h_n|$, then you can show that $g_n$ is uniformly integrable iff $h_n$ is uniformly integrable.

In the proof, something very similar is done. Something close to letting $h_n = |f_n|^p$ and $g_n = |f-f_n|^p$. An extra term is added on, but it is an integrable function which doesn't mess things up.

Can you work it out from here?

Comment: Why is your second sentence true? Why use $1/C$?

Comment: C is some random constant that you find. You can replace $C$ with $C_1$ and $1/C$ with $C_2$ if you prefer.